# Restrict input to the range 1..25 with Angular

Tags: regex, angular

In an input form like the following:

```
<div class="row">
  <label for="input">Value</label>
  <input type="text" id="input" [(ngModel)]="player.input" name="input" 
  required pattern="   ([1-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?|[1][0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})|[2][0-4]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?|25|25.0|25.00)" #input="ngModel">
  <div [hidden]="input.valid || input.pristine"
  class="alert alert-danger">
  input must be between 1-25 with decimal places
</div>
</div>
```

How can I restrict the input to the range of 1 to 25, inclusive, with two decimal places?

Valid inputs: 25.00, 24.99, 08.89, 9.98

Invalid inputs: 255.00, 244.999, 24.999

Comment: Are leading zeros accepted? `0012.35`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^(([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])(\.[0-9]{1,2})?|25|25\.0|25\.00)$
```

Explanation:

```
(
    [1-9]        match 1-9
    1[0-9]       match 10-19
    2[0-4]       match 20-24
)
(\.[0-9]{1,2})?  match an optional decimal component with 1 or 2 digits
|25|25\.0|25\.00 or match 25, 25.0, or 25.00 exactly
```

### Demo

Comment: thanks a lot..it worked.. but a small problem that it's accepting 25.99(for example)..Though it was solved

Comment: @AbhishekSaha I updated per your requirements.  Now `25.00` is allowed, by `25.99` disallowed (as well as any number greater than `25.00`).